# Why is There an Arbitrary Limit of 2..36 for The Base in an Erlang Number Literal?

Tags: erlang

When using the `base#value` notation for integer literals in Erlang, the base can range from 2 to 36 only. Is there a rationale behind the upper limit being 36?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

26 latin characters: a to z, + 10 digits 0 to 9,

I guess there is no other reason :o)

Comment: Makes sense. I thought there was something deeper behind it not being a power of 2.